# screen capture with 2 windows forms

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to make a screen capture application, but I am having a problem understanding the code. From what I understand the Form2 window is the part that will be captured. So then why does FOrm1 cover the entire screen when I run this application? How can I make the Form1 window be visible and then when a button is clicked activate the mousedown event and hide the Form1 to system trey? Here is an example of what I see and nothing else [image] i only want to activate the region screenshot when the button is pressed. Not right away.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
        Form2.Show()
        Form2.Location = Cursor.Position
        Form2.Location = Form2.Location
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
        Form2.Size = Cursor.Position - Form2.Location
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
        Form2.Hide()
        Me.Hide()
        Dim bounds As Form2
        Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
        Dim graph As Graphics
        bounds = Form2
        screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
        graph.CopyFromScreen(Form2.Bounds.X, Form2.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
        Form2.BackgroundImage = screenshot
        Dim sPath As New SaveFileDialog
        sPath.Filter = "Image (*.png)|*,*"
        sPath.ShowDialog()
        Dim bmp As Bitmap
        Try
            bmp = Form2.BackgroundImage
            bmp.Save(sPath.FileName + ".png")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        Try
            If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
                Me.Visible = False
                ScreenShot.Visible = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This will go wrong on XP.  You didn't wait long enough to allow all the other windows to repaint themselves.  You'll have to sleep for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use one Form as the start form and place a button there "Do Screenshot".
Then create a second form, that is maximized and borderless and create a picturebox on it  with location (0, 0) and size of the form itself. Anchor this picturebox to all sides of Form2 (so it scales with it just in case).
When you click on the button on Form1 you could do the following:

```
Private Sub CaptureScreen()
    Dim dWidth As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
    Dim dHeight As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(dWidth, dHeight)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, New Size(dWidth, dHeight))
    g.Dispose()
    If Not IsNothing(Form2.PictureBox1.Image) Then Form2.PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
    Form2.PictureBox1.Image = bmp
    Form2.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    CaptureScreen()
End Sub
```

On Form2 you can then handle the MouseDown, MouseMove and MouseUp events of the Picturebox to let the user draw a rectangle on the image and crop the image at these bounds.
Form2 could look something like that:

```
Public Class Form2
Dim IsDragging As Boolean = False
Dim DragStart As Point = New Point(0, 0)
Dim DragEnd As Point = New Point(0, 0)
Dim OriginalImage As Bitmap
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
Dim LastTime As Date = Date.Now

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If (Date.Now - LastTime).TotalMilliseconds < 15 Then Exit Sub
    If IsDragging Then
        DragEnd = e.Location
        ShowRectangle()
    End If
    LastTime = Date.Now
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
    If IsDragging AndAlso DragStart.X <> DragEnd.X AndAlso DragStart.Y <> DragEnd.Y Then

        'Do the cropping on OriginalImage here

        If Not IsNothing(PictureBox1.Image) Then PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
        PictureBox1.Image = CType(OriginalImage.Clone, Bitmap)
    End If
    IsDragging = False
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    If Not IsNothing(OriginalImage) Then OriginalImage.Dispose()
    OriginalImage = CType(PictureBox1.Image.Clone, Bitmap)
    DragStart = e.Location
    DragEnd = e.Location
    IsDragging = True


End Sub
Private Sub ShowRectangle()
    If (Not IsNothing(OriginalImage)) AndAlso DragStart.X <> DragEnd.X AndAlso DragStart.Y <> DragEnd.Y Then
        Dim NewBmp As Bitmap = CType(OriginalImage.Clone, Bitmap)
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(NewBmp)
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Math.Min(DragStart.X, DragEnd.X), Math.Min(DragStart.Y, DragEnd.Y), Math.Abs(DragStart.X - DragEnd.X), Math.Abs(DragStart.Y - DragEnd.Y))
        g.Dispose()
        If Not IsNothing(PictureBox1.Image) Then PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
        PictureBox1.Image = NewBmp
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```